# java - multiplayer connection

Tags: java, networking, applet, multiplayer

Ok so I'm not Java expert but I'm just programming this java applet game for fun to test my skills. the hardest part so far has been blocked tiles and coming on and off new maps. Anyways, my current game is located at http://mystikrpg.com/jrpg I know, the design is really really simple and bland but I plan on changing that later. They are place-holder graphics.

Anyway, I want to take this to a multiplayer level. I want users to be able to open that browser up and connect and see other players in-game and if they move, the map updates.

Where would I go to start learning how to do this? :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [GameFrame](http://gameframe.sourceforge.net/) or [reddwarf](http://www.reddwarfserver.org/) for that purpose and it will save you a lot of time

Comment: OK I will take a look at those. Thanks! Hopefully I don't have to rewrite a lot (or none) of code... :P

Comment: Anyone have other suggestions..? If so, post 'em!